# Are there Rigger rules for controlling cyberzombies?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

Are there any rules for a GM on cyberzombies in SR5? If so what are they/where can I find them?

Would it be possible for a rigger to control a CZ? Is there anything alike that a rigger can jump into? Thanks

Comment: Do cyberzombies still have meat brains? Or more directly: Is the bit of a cyberzombie that thinks and makes decisions a computer that can be hacked, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

### Sorta.

There are rules for 'jumping in' to CFD-zombies in *Boston Lockdown*.  There are, however, no rules for jumping into cyberzombies (or indeed, any rules for cyberzombies at all).

That said, there are a lot of things in sr5 with no rules whatsoever that are accomplishable in the fluff or previous editions.  My advice is to simply use the existing rules for drones to treat a 'controlled' cyberzombie, and have any cyberzombie that has been fitted with a rigger interface to be jumped into by a rigger (who has ownership of them).  Treat them as Drones, basically.

Answer (score 0):

Rules for cyberzombies are sparse or non-existent.

However cyberzombies seem to lack one component required to jump in: A **Rigger Interface**.

The closest it's going to gets to jumping in a metahuman body can be found in the rules section of *Boston Lockdown* (not meant for players (spoilers)).

> You can indeed use the *Control Device*/*Jump Into Rigged Device* matrix actions on a body infected with CFD(Boston variant).